# Consider the function $f: Z \rightarrow Z/10Z$ defined by $f(x) = [4x]_{10}$, what is $f(A)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Below is the question with its various parts, and it includes my answers. Are these all correct, particularly part $c$?

Consider the function $f: Z \rightarrow Z/10Z$ defined by $f(x) = [4x]_{10}$.

a) What is the image of $f$; i.e., what is $f(Z)$?

b) Compute $f^{-1}(B)$ for each of
        $B = \{[0]_{10}$, $B = \{[1]_{10},[2]_{10}\}$, $B = \{[0]_{10},[2]_{10}\}$, $B = \{[0]_{10},[2]_{10},[6]_{10}\}$.

c) Compute $f(A)$ for each of 
        $A = Z^+$, $A = \{x \in Z: x \mbox{ is even}\}$, $A = \{x \in Z : x \mbox{ is odd}\}$.

Solution:

a) $f(Z)= \{[0]_{10}, [2]_{10}, [4]_{10}, [6]_{10}, [8]_{10} \}$.

b)

When $B= \{[0]_{10}\}, f^{-1}(B) = \{x \in Z : x= 5k, k \in Z\}$.

When $B= \{[1]_{10}, [2]_{10}\}, f^{-1}(B) = \{x \in Z : x= 5k+3, k \in Z\}$.

When $B= \{[0]_{10}, [1]_{10}\}, f^{-1}(B) = \{x \in Z : x= 5k \mbox{ or } x= 5k+3, k \in Z\}$.

When $B= \{[0]_{10}, [2]_{10}, [6]_{10}\}, f^{-1}(B) = \{x \in Z : x = 5k \mbox{ or }x= 5k+3, \mbox{ or } x=5k+4, k \in Z\}$.

c)

When $A= Z^+, f(A)= \{[0]_{10}, [2]_{10}, [4]_{10}, [6]_{10}, [8]_{10}\}$.

When $A= \{x \in X : x \mbox{ is even }\}, f(A)= \{[0]_{10}, [2]_{10}, [4]_{10}, [6]_{10}, [8]_{10}\}$.

When $A= \{x \in X : x \mbox{ is odd }\}, f(A)= \{[0]_{10}, [2]_{10}, [4]_{10}, [6]_{10}, [8]_{10}\}$.

Comment: Seems all good to me.

Comment: Your third line of "When $B=\{[0]_{10},[1]_{10}\}$" seems to be wrong since $f(3)=[2]_{10} \notin B$.